# ActiveRecord::Dirty attributed_changed? is true, even though the attribute hasn't changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have an interesting problem where my model's `status` enum attribute behaves weirdly.

I haven't updated the `status`, but:

```
(byebug) status_changed?
true
(byebug) status_change
["submitted_for_review", "submitted_for_review"]
```

---

This happens when my controller calls:

```
@order.update {"recalculate"=>"true"}
```

Because of the wrong `status_changed?` the following callback is fired:

```
before_save :run_status_callbacks, if: :status_changed?
```

Inside which it ran my `debugger` statement and then I ran the commands in the first block.

---

Why is the `status` attributed being detected as changed even though it hasn't been touched?

Comment: What's your Rails version? Has anything written to that attribute, e.g. another callback?

Comment: @matthewd Rails 5.1.x and no, but give me a moment to confirm.

Comment: @matthewd I disabled all other callbacks, and no, nothing's writing to it.

Comment: If you can reproduce it with the standalone test template at https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/guides/bug_report_templates/active_record_gem.rb (and against 5.2), it sounds like a reportable bug.

Comment: Sighhh, I found the error, it was technically another callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem with a few hours of debugging. Here's the line:

```
validate :can_confirm_order?, if: :status_will_change!
```

It runs the validation, but instead of a `:status_changed?` in the conditional, someone wrote `:status_will_change!`.

This was hard to find because it was in a validation rule, and let's be honest, after a few dozen validation rules in the model, you kinda glance over them all.

Note to self: pay more attention during code reviews.